# Test coverage on PHPUnit 6.5.5 and PHP 7.2

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

the problem is that lines with the switch case are not covered, the switch cases themselves are being executed.

Tested on windows

[image: here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is technically correct, as PHP 7.2 is now clever and no longer needs to run the case statements. I wrote about these optimisations at https://derickrethans.nl/php7.2-switch.html

Nevertheless, this is unwanted behaviour, and hence Xdebug has this "bug" fixed with https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/commit/0690bf83109228a67dfe14a9a312045435b7b774 — this is part of Xdebug's code on GitHub, but has not made it yet into a release. It will make it into Xdebug 2.6.0beta2.

Answer (score 0):

This was (probably) answered in https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2953.

Comment: You get this kind of trouble when you implement a test coverage tool using something that tracks (PHP) virtual instructions (e.g., XDebug), because "case clauses" aren't executed.  You get a similar problem with opening and closing braces on function bodies and if statements for the same reason. If you implement the tool using source code instrumentation, you don't (ever) have this kind of problem.   For a PHP test coverage tool that has always used source instrumentation, see my company's PHP test coverage tool: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/PHPTestCoverage.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

#### Best alternative: pcov

This is more faster than XDebug. More info https://github.com/krakjoe/pcov.

#### Another alternative: XDebug

XDebuyg will always be the best option as it is the one with the most community and time. The bad thing is that it is usually very slow compared to other roads. Dont forget update to last version ;).

#### Temporary solution for phpdbg

Option 1. Use CONSTANTS instead of magic strings. For example:

```
class SectionTypes
{
    public const APP = 'app';
    public const SHARE = 'share';
}

/* ... */

case ($type) {
    case SectionTypes::APP:
        /* do something */
        break;
}
```

Option 2. Use concatenations. For example:

```
case ($type) {
    case 'app'.'':
        /* do something */
        break;
}
```

Off course, the last option is ugly and not very recommended, but it can help you quickly.